# What is a robust strategy for making the Memory limitations a part of a build process?

Tags: java, memory, ant, junit, jvm

**PROBLEM**

I have a build server which passes all tests, but on some machines, tests fail due to memory limitations.

**PROPOSED SOLUTION**

I want to add precise memory limits to my Ant build script - is there a simple way to do this so that All JVM's used to compile, build, and Test my program have the exact same memory specifications ?  Also, please note : I don't want to "spot" fix by adding certain "-Xmx" flags to shell scripts -- rather, i want the memory limits to be a natural and inherent aspect of the ANT build.

MOST IMPORTANTLY : As you might expect, the priority here is that I DO NOT want tests failing due to unknown, machine specific JVM parameters.  Rather, I would like the build to halt altogether, BEFORE compilation/testing/etc if a JVM is below memory requirements.

**RATIONALE**

It is quite troubling when a particular unit test fails due to memory , because you don't know wether the failure is due to bad code (i.e. a memory leak) or simply a bad hardward / JVM setup.  It would thus be desireable to make "memory" a "non-moving" part in a build engine.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on how you're running your tests, which you don't mention.

For example, the [junit task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/junit.html) has `maxmemory` property.

If you're not forking, you may also run into memory issues.

More details would allow people to target answers better.

*After your edit*

*You* specify JVM parameters, even if there are system properties defined on the machine they could be overridden by a user, a CI system, etc.

In addition, tests take an essentially arbitrary amount of memory--unless you know the most memory a test will take, in real life, I don't see how the potential to run out of memory can be eliminated.

Your Ant build, scripts, and task parameters *are* the way to define consistent memory parameters and ensure the execution JVM is in a consistent state when it starts up.

Comment: Thanks - so ... whats the prescription for your last bullet ?  How can I ensure the consistent state of the JVM ?  I AM in fact forking, so I guess you are suggesting that increasing the maxmemory parameter  for the unit test task is the way to go ... ?  I have found that this works on my machine.. but I want to make sure its the right way to ensure the consistency of JVM state for a multi developer CI system.

Comment: @jayunit100 I think we just set up script params for the CI servers and forked tests with a max memory for the junit tests, and used whatever mechanism(s) available for non-junit tests. Not something we worried about a lot; a leak would manifest pretty much no matter what, non-leaks we'd just tweak memory params.